# Spring micrometer actuator StatsD tags definition

Tags: spring, tags, spring-boot-actuator, micrometer

I'm trying to configure spring actuator metrics along with micrometer to be sent to Datadog stastd agent.

Still, I'd like to get them all sent with a tag, so that I can filter in my Datadog dashboard just my service metrics, and not considering other services metrics.

I've added:

```
management:
  metrics:
    tags:
      application: my_app
```

to my service metrics configuration, but I can't see this tag value in Datadog dashboard. I'm not seeing anything weird in app logs nor actuator logfile neither.

I have nothing else regarding metrics in my service, as I don't want to implement custom metrics, just want to use the one provided by actuator.

This is how the whole metrics configuration looks like:

```
management:
  metrics:
    export:
      statsd:
        host: ${STATSD_AGENT_HOST}
        port: ${STATSD_AGENT_HOST_PORT}
        flavor: datadog
    tags:
      application: my_app
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: "*"
  endpoint:
    health:
      show-details: ALWAYS
```

Versions:

micrometer version: 1.6.4

actuator version: 2.4.3

spring version: 2.3.8

Any clue about what I could be missing to get the tag reaching Datadog?

Thanks!

Comment: just for clarification, is it only that single tag that is not transmitted to datadog or is it that all tags are not transmitted?

Comment: Just that tag AFAIK. As I wrote, I haven't configured nor implemented anything else. Still, not easy to check as this service metrics are getting mixed with other metrics as I can't filter them out.

Comment: `management.metrics.tags.application` should definitely add the tag.
Could you please check `/actuator/metrics` if you see the tag on any metrics listed there?
By "spring version" you mean spring-boot? If so, spring-boot modules should match so if you are using spring-boot-actuator 2.4.3, everything should be 2.4.3.
2.3.x and 2.4.x are not compatible.

Comment: I can't see the tag in any metric listed on `/actuator/metrics`  I just see metrics as default, "http.server.requests", "jvm.buffer.count", "jvm.buffer.memory.used" etc. When accessing details fo any of those metrics, I can't either see the tag in the `available_tags` list. Yes, by spring version I mean spring-boot. I didn't know abou that compatibility requirement among versions. I didn't see any compatibility report in app logs. Still, I'm going to try with actuator 2.3.x and check again.

Comment: You were right @JonatanIvanov that was the issue. Version incompatibility. Now, with spring-boot-starter-actuator set to 2.3.8.RELEASE version, when accessing any metric, for example `/actuator/metrics/jvm.buffer.count` among the tags listed under `available_tags` I can see `application` tag set to the value I set in application.yml config file. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We figured this out in the comments, I'm posting an answer that summarizes it all up: it seems the root cause was using different versions of different spring-boot modules.

It is a good rule of thumb to not define the versions yourself but use BOMs and let them define the versions for you, e.g. see: [spring-boot-dependencies](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-dependencies/2.4.3/pom). This way you will use the compatible (and tested) versions.

`management.metrics.tags.your-tag` is the way to add tags to all of your metrics. A good way to check this is looking at `/actuator/metrics`.